# Why "std::vector<std::string> &" instead of "void"?

Tags: c++, string

I would like to use the string splitting function for the highest rated answer to this question:

[Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

Copying the answer for convenience:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

I have a question here. Why the declaration is `std::vector<std::string> &split(...)` rather than `void split(...)`? As an argument we receive `std::vector<std::string> &elems` and this is what we want to end up having. Why return anything if we receive a reference?

I have:

```
int &multA (int &n)
{
    n = 5*n;
    return n;
}

void multB (int &n)
{
    n = 5*n;
}
```

and:

```
int n1, n2;
n1 = 1;
n2 = 1;
cout << "n1: " << n1 << endl;
cout << "n2: " << n2 << endl;
n1 = multA(n1);
multB(n2);
cout << "n1: " << n1 << endl;
cout << "n2: " << n2 << endl;
```

And as a result I have:

```
n1: 1
n2: 1
n1: 5
n2: 5
```

What's the difference then?

Comment: It's just a convenience so you can use the return value as an lvalue if desired.

Comment: It should have something to do with memory management

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning a reference allows a call to `split()` to be used as an argument to another function.  For example, assume we have some other function that accepts a vector of strings by reference

```
  void func(std::vector<std::string> &elements);
```

If `split()` returns a reference, it is possible to pass the reference it returns directly to `func()`.

```
  func(split(s, delim, elems));
```

whereas, if `split()` did not return a reference, it would be necessary to do

```
  split(s,delim, elems);
  func(elems);
```

The second usage approach still works if `split()` returns a reference.

The difference between these two is purely programmer convenience, but a lot of programmers prefer to use the first calling style.  Returning a reference is not a particularly expensive operation so allowing the programmer a choice in how to use it does not lose much.

Answer (score 3):

It's syntactic sugar that make the functions more flexible.

By example: you can write

```
std::cout << "there are " << split(str, delim, vect).size() << " elemements\n";
```

With the `void` hypothesis case, you need 2 statements.

Comment: It would be more correct to use the word "statements" rather than "instructions".

Comment: @ Peter - thanks; I'm not native English speaker so often I fail using the correct terms (and maybe I'm wrong in my language too); I correct my answer.

Comment: No problem, but the english in your answer was (and is) fine.  The word "statement" has a specific meaning in C++.   The word "instruction" (in this context) has a particular meaning in computer science,  which differs from a statement in C++.   That sample of code you gave is a single C++ statement.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the examples you posted.

But there might be if you want to assign it to another variable and/or pass it to a function.

```
int a = multA(n1); //In one line :)
foo(multA(na1));   //Same thing, one line only

multB(n1);
int a = n1; //Two lines

multB(n1);
foo(n1);    //Two lines
```

Here `multA` is clearly better, because you can write it in one line, instead of 2 with `multB`. So basically the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

In term of result, there is no difference at all between these two methods.

However, option 1 makes it clear that the function `multA` has a computational result and that result is returned.

```
n1 = multA(n1);
```

On the other hand, the second option is not as self-explanatory as the first one. You cannot easily tell what `multB` is doing by reading the following code. It could be possible that `multB` is just logging a result with `std::cout`. But you cannot tell without reading the function definition.

```
multB(n2);
```